# Yii2 listBox multi select item

Tags: php, yii2

I try to make preselected in listbox but it doesn't work.

When I try with other option like label or something it work but selected doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
    $form->field($model, 'offerCategory')->listBox([
            'monday' => 'Monday',
            'tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
            'wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
            'thursday' => 'Thursday',
            'friday' => 'Friday',
            'saturday' => 'Saturday',
            'sunday' => 'Sunday'], 
            ['options' => ['monday' => ['selected' => 'selected'],
                           'tuesday' => ['selected' => 'selected'],
                           'wednesday' => ['label' => 'test']
                          ],
            'multiple' => 'true',
    ])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set model attributes first:

```
<?php $model->offerCategory = ['monday', 'tuesday'] ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'offerCategory')->listBox([
        'monday' => 'Monday',
        'tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
        'wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
        'thursday' => 'Thursday',
        'friday' => 'Friday',
        'saturday' => 'Saturday',
        'sunday' => 'Sunday'
        ],['multiple' => 'true',
    ]) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I looked all over but this was EXACTLY what we needed.

Comment: Also, I think, the best way of doing this is putting <?php $model->offerCategory = ['monday', 'tuesday'] ?> in your Controller